# declaring a list inside a class and it's the same list in every instance?

Tags: c#, list, class, encapsulation

I created a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
 {
     public List<int> Params = new List<int>();

      public void Load(int data)
        {
            Params.Add(data);
        }
}
```

Then i initiate, let's say, three instances of the class.

```
MyClass one = new MyClass();
MyClass two = new MyClass();
MyClass three = new MyClass();
```

add the list with data:

```
one.Load(10);
two.Load(50);
three.Load(100);
```

then surprisingly when i check:

```
one.Params.Count();
```

the count is 3, also

```
two.Params.Count();
```

is also 3

each instance list got three numbers - i.e. the same list.
Somehow instead of separated lists i got pointers to the same list.
How would you make it into three different stand alone lists with each instance ?

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Please show us your _actual_ code.  You're probably misusing `static`, or forgetting to copy something.

Comment: Downvoted because the code as posted does not compile (due to `Public` being capitalized in the declaration of `Params`) and thus **cannot** be exhibiting the claimed behavior.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help. I'll try posting working code and not just the concept in future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like nothing is wrong in the code you presented in the Original Post.

Click [here](http://ideone.com/Nx6qhe) to see the live output for following code.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       MyClass one = new MyClass();
        MyClass two = new MyClass();
        MyClass three = new MyClass();

        one.Load(10);
        two.Load(50);
        three.Load(100);

        System.Console.WriteLine("One.Count  " + one.Params.Count);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Two.Count " +two.Params.Count);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Three.Count  "+ three.Params.Count);
    }
}

public class MyClass
 {
     public List<int> Params = new List<int>();

      public void Load(int data)
        {
            Params.Add(data);
        }
}
```

All One.Params.Count, Two.Params.Count and Three.Params.Count are returning 1.

As pointed out in comments, you are probably declaring Params as Static. In that case output will be 3 as all instance shares the same List.

Comment: my bad. I've found the error as i was addressing the same instance again and again, thus duplicating it. Maybe it's the late hour here. Thanks you, your answer made me realize the error and fix it swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be that way by default.  Are you sure you haven't made the class or the field static?

Using the following code

```
    public class MyClass {
        public List<int> Params = new List<int>();
        public void Load(int data) {
            Params.Add(data);
            }
        }

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var one = new MyClass();
        var two = new MyClass();
        var three = new MyClass();

        one.Load(25);
        two.Load(50);            
        three.Load(75);

        Console.WriteLine(one.Params.Count());

        }
     }
```

I get the expected answer of 1 and when I use the debugger to check classes two and three I also see that their lists contain only 1 item.